# Python or Unix/bash. Rename 11th column of each file within a directory

Tags: python, bash, sed

I have a directory with thousands of .txt files. In each file, the 11th column has a different name. This is an example of the first few lines of one .txt file:

```
ID  maxage  gender  GA_NAT  GA_EUR  pv  Y   M   C   A   rs148292867
1   16  0   0.4443  0.5298  7.378472    0.01692 0.451366    0.526591     0.005124   0
2   17.1362080766598    0   0.3377  0.6463  7.639588    0.007403    0.333114    0.659472    0.00001 0
4   15.937029431896 1   0.4398  0.5227  9.082893    0.016812    0.410415    0.538821    0.033953    0
```

Using Python or Unix/Bash, I want to rename the eleventh column of each file with the name "GT". I am trying something like:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob("/mypath/*.txt")

for i in range(len(files)):
    from_file = open(files[i]) 
    # add to each file columns.values[11] = "GT"

    to_file = open(files[i], mode="w")
    to_file.write("")
    shutil.copyfileobj(from_file, to_file)
```

I am sure there is a simple way to do this, but I am not able to.

Comment: Might be more simple to use `awk`.

Comment: Hi @S3DEV, I just edit the post to include unix/bash

Comment: A "field" can mean many things, depending on the format of the file. Is it: csv, tsv, fixed-width, or something else? It might help if you include the top few lines of one of the files.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, I just added the first lines of one file. They are tsv. Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the field you want to replace is always the last field on the line?

Comment: @r2evans, yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's safe to assume that the 11th is always the last field on that line, then I suggest `sed` can do this well (as can `awk`).

Copying your sample lines into two files `quux1.txt` and `quux2.txt`, I can do

```bash
$ cat quux[12].txt
ID  maxage  gender  GA_NAT  GA_EUR  pv  Y   M   C   A   rs148292867
1   16  0   0.4443  0.5298  7.378472    0.01692 0.451366    0.526591     0.005124   0
2   17.1362080766598    0   0.3377  0.6463  7.639588    0.007403    0.333114    0.659472    0.00001 0
4   15.937029431896 1   0.4398  0.5227  9.082893    0.016812    0.410415    0.538821    0.033953    0
ID  maxage  gender  GA_NAT  GA_EUR  pv  Y   M   C   A   rs148292867
1   16  0   0.4443  0.5298  7.378472    0.01692 0.451366    0.526591     0.005124   0
2   17.1362080766598    0   0.3377  0.6463  7.639588    0.007403    0.333114    0.659472    0.00001 0
4   15.937029431896 1   0.4398  0.5227  9.082893    0.016812    0.410415    0.538821    0.033953    0

$ sed -i -E '1 s/\S+\s*$/GT/g' quux[12].txt

$ cat quux[12].txt
ID  maxage  gender  GA_NAT  GA_EUR  pv  Y   M   C   A   GT
1   16  0   0.4443  0.5298  7.378472    0.01692 0.451366    0.526591     0.005124   0
2   17.1362080766598    0   0.3377  0.6463  7.639588    0.007403    0.333114    0.659472    0.00001 0
4   15.937029431896 1   0.4398  0.5227  9.082893    0.016812    0.410415    0.538821    0.033953    0
ID  maxage  gender  GA_NAT  GA_EUR  pv  Y   M   C   A   GT
1   16  0   0.4443  0.5298  7.378472    0.01692 0.451366    0.526591     0.005124   0
2   17.1362080766598    0   0.3377  0.6463  7.639588    0.007403    0.333114    0.659472    0.00001 0
4   15.937029431896 1   0.4398  0.5227  9.082893    0.016812    0.410415    0.538821    0.033953    0
```

(Note that `-i` is in-place editing, this data is lost after this operation. If you need to save backups, you can either `-i.bak -E` or just copy them out of the way manually.)

Comment: Thank you @r2evans. Will this script do it for all the files (~1,000,000) within the directory?

Comment: Depending on the file grob you use (`quux[12].txt` here), yes. Be careful with the filename wildcards you use.